# OpenCV - capture footage from a Black Magic Mini Recorder?

Tags: python, opencv

What is the best way to get a video feed from a Black Magic Mini Recorder (Thunderbolt connection) into an OpenCV Mat (Python)?

I'm using Mac OS X El Capitan, Blackmagic Desktop Video SDK 10.7 and OpenCV 3.0.0.

**Edit:**

I tried using VideoCapture like so:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And it gave me the following error:
(I assume it's because `cap` is empty)

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /tmp/opencv3-20160626-61731-v18vfg/opencv-3.1.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 281
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 69, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
cv2.error: /tmp/opencv3-20160626-61731-v18vfg/opencv-3.1.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:281: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow

QTKit didn't find any attached Video Input Devices!
Warning, camera failed to properly initialize!
Cleaned up camera.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just using the VideoCapture function which didn't work.

Comment: I edited my original post with what i've tried and the error i got.

Comment: Did you install OpenCV using `homebrew`? If so, it *may* help if you use `brew install opencv3 --with-gstreamer`... https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/kivy-users/fQ0p5WA3t5k

Comment: I stopped getting the `assertion` error but the one with `QTKit` is still there..

Comment: Just as a little experiment, maybe try setting the resolution to something small - maybe 640x480 and see if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work..